# Pass PHP form data from child window to parent window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two windows, one is a parent, the other is a child.

When a link is clicked, it opens the popup window (the child), and then you submit the info in the form. Now the new form data from the child window needs to be passed to the parent window so that I can update the form data into the parent window.

I am using PHP and Javascript and jQuery. How do I do this?

I know there is a similar question, but my problem is that I need to submit the form data and pass that new data to the parent window. I can not just do the lazy way and grab the input of child window, because I also need the new ID of the object that gets added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you submit the data from the child form to the server via ajax, and once you get the newly created id back, pass the data (with the new id) back to the parent?

Comment: Yes but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that there's any way that you could do it without any really complicated way. Instead of opening a new window, you could just make a popup on the same window and inside the popup you could put an iFrame linking to your form stuff. Because that way you could just grab the data from the iFrame. Or instead of using an iframe you could just load the content of the child window using Ajax.